# What is the difference between partial order relations and equivalence relations?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

From googling it, I understood that a relation is both a *partial order relation* and an *equivalence relation* when they are *reflexive*, *symmetric* and *transitive*. So it appears they are the same. But as far I know, they are not supposed to be the same.

What is the difference between partial order relations and equivalence relations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you misread slightly: partial orders and equivalence relations are both reflexive and transitive, but only equivalence relations are symmetric, while partial orders are *anti*symmetric.  A relation $R$ is symmetric if $aRb$ implies $bRa$, while a relation $R$ is antisymmetric if $aRb$ and $bRA$ implies $a=b$.

For example, the relation "has the same parity as" is symmetric (and in fact an equivalence relation) on the integers, since if $a$ has the same parity as $b$ then $b$ has the same parity as $a$.  On the other hand, it is not antisymmetric, because $2$ has the same parity as $4$ and $4$ has the same parity as $2$, even though $2\neq 4$.

The relation $\leq$ on integers, in contrast, is antisymmetric (and in fact a partial order), since if $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ then $a=b$.  But it is not symmetric, since (for instance) $2\leq 4$ but $4\not\leq 2$.